# Stop SharePoint Displaying Meeting Attendees NT Username

Tags: sharepoint, meetings, username

I've created a meetingspace in SharePoint and added some users to the attendees list. Most of the users name comes up fine (e.g. John Smith is displayed) but for others the NT username is displayed (e.g. DOMAIN\smithjohn). Removing users and adding them again sometimes works, but not always.
How can I get the list to always display the users name rather than NT username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do regular synchronizing of your AD to SharePoint

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-7-SharePoint_2007__All_you_ever_wanted_to_know_about_User_Profiles.aspx